# Search for Companies by Revenue

Tags: research

Is there a site that allows you to search for all US companies by different factors such as geography, revenue, industry, etc? I am using crunchbase and owler, but crunchbase doesn't allow me to search by revenue and owler doesn't have a very large database.

Comment: All companies? Or all *publicly held* companies?

Comment: Specifically companies with revenues between $5 and $175 million. It doesn't matter if they are public or private.

Comment: Cody, welcome to money.SE. So far, 4 of your 5 questions have been put on hold as off-topic. Please take a few minutes to [Take the tour](https://money.stackexchange.com/tour) and see what kind of questions are appropriate here. For someone with a particular narrow interest, it might seem that the board is pretty tough, but if you take the time, you'll see a wide range of helpful Q&A.

Comment: @CodyRutscher It does matter if they're public or private, because private companies don't have to disclose their finances, making their information largely unavailable, especially for smaller companies that are largely out of the spotlight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The various free screeners at FINVIZ will allow you to see dozens of metrics on US companies that trade on the AMEX, NASDAQ and NYSE.

https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=161